# GMSAutocompleteViewController get complete address

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I'm using GMSAutocompleteViewController in order to let the user search for an address.
How can I get address details from GMSAutocompleteViewController after the user choose a suggestion ?
I'm using

```
func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
```

to get the result of the UI controller. Then I'm reverse geocoding in order to get an GMSAddress. The code is like this:

```
GMSGeocoder().reverseGeocodeCoordinate(place.coordinate, completionHandler: { (response:GMSReverseGeocodeResponse?, err:Error?) in
...
let firstAddr:GMSAddress = (response?.firstResult())!
```

I was able to get city, country from firstAddr. But I need separate results for street and street number in case they are. I tried to use *thoroughfare* and addressLine1, *addressLine2* but without result, they return a combination of street and street number and I don't have a patter to split it.

Is it an easy way to obtain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the complete address string use

> place.formattedAddress

To get the each field in the address, using addressComponents array.

> place.addressComponents